# Unable to call method in Main()?

Tags: c#, methods, syntax-error

Hello I am learning C#.

When trying to call my Method in a instance, I don't get the option for intellesence and am forced to type it.

I also have the current two errors when trying to build:

1.)"'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'LastWriteTime' and no extension method 'LastWriteTime' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found."

2.)"Member 'MyClass.Move_Modified_Files()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
namespace File_Mover
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static string src = @"C:\Users\Bold Defiance\Desktop\FolderA";
        public static string dst = @"C:\Users\Bold Defiance\Desktop\FolderB";
       public static string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(src, "*.txt");

        public static void Move_Modified_Files()
        {
            try
            {
                if (files.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
                {
                    File.Move(src, dst);
                    Console.WriteLine("Modified files in {0} were moved to {1}", src, dst);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No new or modified files were created today.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass cls = new MyClass();
            cls.Move_Modified_Files();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your errors:

1.)`System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` returns an array of file paths. If you want to check the last write time of each file, you can use `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime()` passing it the full path.  You'll have to loop over the array to accomplish this.

2.) Your method and member variables are static in the class and do not need to be. You should make the method non-static and then this error/warning will go away.

Comment: Also, the way it is written, `File.Move` will attempt to act on a directory. If it doesn't throw an exception it would only move the folder itself into the other. `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` would probably be better suited with its return of FileInfo objects (to directly query LastWriteTime, and access MoveTo) and its lazy evaluation (for larger directories anyways)